# Failing on invoke HibernateCursorItemReader's close method

Tags: spring-batch

I have a `@JobScope` HibernateCursorItemReader that is failing on close method because my cursor is already closed and it is being called twice by `AbstractStep.close()` and `JobSynchronizationManager.release()`.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("job.entity")
public class EntityJobConfig {

    @Setter
    @NotNull(message = "chunkSize cannot be null")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "chunkSize must be 1 at least")
    private int chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    Job job() {
        return this.jobs.get("job")
            .start(this.step())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Step step() {
        return this.steps.get("step")
            .<Entity, Entity>chunk(this.chunkSize)
            .reader(this.reader(null))
            .writer(this.writer())      
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    HibernateCursorItemReader<Entity> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['entityId']}") Integer entityId) {
        HibernateCursorItemReader<Entity> reader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setUseStatelessSession(false);
        reader.setSessionFactory(this.entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class));
        reader.setFetchSize(this.chunkSize);
        reader.setQueryString("...");
        reader.setParameterValues(ImmutableMap.of("entityId", entityId));
        return reader;
    }
}
```

Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Could you please add your configuration, before concluding if its bug?

Comment: Question updated with my config.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work fine if you use `@StepScope`?

Comment: @DeanClark No, close method is called twice too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to dig a bit to figure out why `@StepScope` or `@JobScope` is closing a reader/writer, but regardless, this is something we could easily fix in the reader.  I've opened a Jira issue to track addressing this.  You can track it here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2619